# Play PS2 data on remastered PS3 game

Tags: ps3, backwards-compatibility, ps2

I have reading up on this online but I haven't found anything. Say I were to copy data from my PS2 memory card and transfer it to my PS3, using Sony's memory card adapter. Could I then use this data on a game made for the PS3? The game is Tomb Raider Anniversary, it has been re-made for the PS3 along with Legend and Underworld.

So could anyone confirm if I could play my PS2 save game on the PS3 version of the game?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Original PS2 and PS1 games running on the PS3 (this applies both to the disc versions and the downloadable versions from the PSN store) save and load to virtual memory cards on the system. If you use the adapter on your original memory cards, they'll transfer into these virtual cards and be usable by the original versions.

Remastered (i.e. HD) versions of PS2 games, however, use the PS3 save data format, and don't access the memory cards at all. So unfortunately, no, this won't work.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I will have to stick to my PS2 until I start playing one of them on PS3 to start with :)